# Changing icon of javaframe in MATLAB compiled application

Tags: matlab, jframe

I have developed a standalone MATLAB application. To replace the MATLAB icon on the figure window with a custom made one, I used the following code:

```
jframe = get(hFig,'javaframe');
S1=pwd; S2='\appleo.png'; S={[S1 S2]};
jIcon=javax.swing.ImageIcon(S);
jframe.setFigureIcon(jIcon);
```

When the program is run in MATLAB, it works fine and I get the new icon for the figure window. But when this program is packaged to a standalone application, the 'MATLAB icon' is replaced with a 'Java icon' not with the custom made one. Why? What is the way out?

Comment: As a side note, be aware that replacing that icon is in breach with TMW license.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mainly that you're getting the location of your PNG file from the command `pwd`, and for a compiled application that command won't give the same results as it does from within regular MATLAB.

When compiling applications, you need to be careful where to locate resource files like this - you need to package them within the compiled application, and then in the code refer to their location relative to the output of the command `ctfroot`, which gives you the path into which the compiled application is unpacked.

You have a second problem as well, though, which is that replacing the icon of a figure window is explicitly forbidden by the license agreement of MATLAB and MATLAB Compiler. What you're doing is in breach of the license.

Finally, fairly soon you will have a third problem, which is that over the next few releases MathWorks will be moving away from figure windows that are based on Java, and towards HTML-based figure windows (see the App Designer from more recent release, which forms the initial phase of this). So if you plan on developing your app in future versions of MATLAB, you won't be able to change the window icon in this way, as the window won't have a Java Frame.